# How to change transparency of texture in shader

Tags: opengl-es, shader, alpha

I wanna create shader what will be changing alpha color of texture from invisible to visible.

I've seen method to change gl_FragColor.a. But for me it doesn't work. What ever i setting there always all screen is black.

```
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 vColor;
uniform sampler2D uTexture;
varying vec2 vTexCoordinate;
uniform float alphaMod;

void main(){

    gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture, vTexCoordinate);
    gl_FragColor.a = alphaMod;
}
```

Modified object should be barely visible but for now is invisible.

Comment: 1. Do you see the texture if you delete the line `gl_FragColor.a = alphaMod;`? 2. If yes, then what happens if you set `gl_FragColor.a = 0.5;`

Comment: When i set gl_FragColor.a = 0.5; then texture is barely visible. But i dont understand why it happens. Stiil when it is 0 or 1 texture is invisible.

Comment: do you set `gl_FragColor.a = 1;` or `gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;`?

Comment: I was setting just 1. Setting 1.0 fixing this.

Comment: If `gl_FragColor.a = alphaMod;` doesn't work, then the issue is when you set the uniform.

Comment: Yes you have right. I was calling bad variable. Thanks for explanation how to change gl_FragColor.